# Disable PIC for link in CMake

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake, shared-libraries, position-independent-code

I have a C++ project in CMake (32-bit shared library) and gcc compiler. I set `POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE` property to `OFF` for my project, so it removes `-fPIC` only for source compiling, but not for link stage too. How can I disable it for link?

I know there is a way with `-fno-PIC` in `LINK_FLAGS`. And also also I can set `CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_CXX_FLAGS` to `""`. But these ways looks dirty.

Comment: Linker itself has no option controlling "pic": all such options are passed to it from the compiler. So, if your compiler flags do not contain `-fPIC`, linker flags shouldn't contain this option too... Unless someone specified `-fPIC` **directly** for linker, which is wrong approach. Could you provide an example demonstating your problem (as a [mcve])?

Comment: @Tsyvarev [CMakeLists.txt](https://gist.github.com/WPMGPRoSToTeMa/241ef49b9c868f2d21bd6a88ab3c8c56)